# Change the slotDuartion dynamically in fullcalendar view. When slide the slider

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

When i slide the slider to some hours the fullcalendar not changed in the view.

What error are you getting?
Not changing view in fullcalendar as per slotduartion

When i slide the slider to some hours (Within 24 hrs.) the fullcalendar should change the view by calling the function. The view of fullcalender should change when slide the slider.

```js
var datetime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
var slotduartion = '';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        timeZone: 'UTC',
        slotMinTime: '06:00',
        slotMaxTime: '19:00',
        slotDuration: slotduartion,
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
        height: 650,
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
        },
        slotLabelFormat: { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false },
        allDay: false,
        editable: true,
        resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Manager',
        initialDate: today,
        businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
            {
                daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
                startTime: '07:00', // 8am
                endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
            }

        ],

        resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'Employee 1' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'Employee 2' },
            { id: 'c', title: 'Employee 3' },
            { id: 'd', title: 'Employee 4' }
        ],
        events: [
            { title: 'Event 1', start: today + 'T07:30:00', end: today + 'T12:00:00', resourceId: 'a' },
            { title: 'Event 2', start: today + 'T09:30:00', end: today + 'T14:00:00', resourceId: 'b' },
            { title: 'Event 3', start: today + 'T08:30:00', end: today + 'T12:00:00', resourceId: 'c' },
            { title: 'Event 4', start: today + 'T10:30:00', end: today + 'T14:00:00', resourceId: 'd' }
        ]
    });
    calendar.render();
});

var value = 0;
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("displayValue");
var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
var minutes = slider.value % 60;
var seconds = minutes * 60;
var minuteOutput = $("#minutes")[0];
var hourOutput = $("#hours")[0];
var secondOutput = $("#seconds")[0];
var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
var minutes = slider.value % 60;
var seconds = minutes * 60;
hourOutput.innerHTML = hours;
minuteOutput.innerHTML = minutes;
secondOutput.innerHTML = seconds

$('.slider').change(function () {
    debugger;
    var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
    var minutes = slider.value % 60;
    var seconds = minutes * 60;
    hourOutput.innerHTML = hours;
    minuteOutput.innerHTML = minutes;
    secondOutput.innerHTML = seconds;
    slotduartion = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
});
```

```css
a {
            color: var(--bs-link-color);
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #storlekslider {
            width: 30%;
        }
```

```html
<head>
         <meta charset='utf-8' />
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.9/index.global.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <h3 id="displayValue">
            <span id="hours">min</span> :
            <span id="minutes">hour</span>
            <span id="seconds" style="display:none;">second</span>
        </h3>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="1440" value="500" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you using two different versions of fullcalendar in your code??? Just use version 6. You don't need version 2 as well. And if you want to change the slot duration of the existing calendar you've already loaded, then use `calendar.setOption` to do that, as per [the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options)

Comment: P.S. You also have 2 different versions of jquery, and 3 different versions of jQuery-UI mentioned in your various `<script` and `<link` tags. It's a mess and you need to sort it out, otherwise it can cause issues (and certainly it's very inefficient to load lots of redundant content). You need pay more care and attention to the details of your code, it seems.

Comment: If you edit the questions code to fix things said in the comments, it's a bit confusing for people who come a little later. Aside from that, there are still 2 versions of jQuery UI. I think the advice of @ADyson is spot on. Take your time to clean up your code, add comments and maybe add some logs to better know what is going on :)

Comment: Hey hello @ADyson thank you for your time. I corrected the code as per your answer  calendar.setOption it will through error saying that calendar.setOption is not a function

Comment: You still have 2 different jquery versions and 3 different jquery-UI versions in there. That still needs correcting.

Comment: `calendar.setOption is not a function`...most likely that's because `calendar` isn't in scope when you're trying to use it. A simple fix to that would be to make sure it's a global variable. Or you could move all the slider code inside the `DOMContentLoaded` block, so it has the same scope as `calendar` anyway. And that would make sense more generally - you likely want to wait until the page is loaded before trying to reference objects on it.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson for  answering my questions' and solving problem. Ya i will correct the jquery & UI version.

Comment: Hello @ADyson could you run the code and have look . when slotLabelInterval changes based on slide the slider. Is it the events position should change ?

Comment: If you have a new problem, please ask a new question about it with all the relevant information. Don't change your current question to ask about a different issue - it makes the existing answers make no sense. I've rolled back your edit. Post a new question so that we can take a look at it properly, while still preserving the answer to your original problem for future users. Thanks.

Comment: Sure @ADyson i will frame new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the calendar variable outside the event, reference that in the slider and use [`setOption`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options#setting) to change the value

```
var calendar = null;
// ...
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        // options
    });
    calendar.render();
});
// ...
$('.slider').change(function () {
    // ...
    if(calendar) {
        calendar.setOption('slotDuration', slotduartion);
    }
});
```

I have added the updated snippet, please note that I have not fixed the slider function that creates the [`duration object`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration-object).

```js
var calendar = null;
var datetime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
var slotduartion = '';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    slotMinTime: '06:00',
    slotMaxTime: '19:00',
    slotDuration: slotduartion,
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
    height: 650,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    slotLabelFormat: {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: '2-digit',
      hour12: false
    },
    allDay: false,
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Manager',
    initialDate: today,
    businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
      {
        daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
        startTime: '07:00', // 8am
        endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
      }

    ],

    resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
    resources: [{
        id: 'a',
        title: 'Employee 1'
      },
      {
        id: 'b',
        title: 'Employee 2'
      },
      {
        id: 'c',
        title: 'Employee 3'
      },
      {
        id: 'd',
        title: 'Employee 4'
      }
    ],
    events: [{
        title: 'Event 1',
        start: today + 'T07:30:00',
        end: today + 'T12:00:00',
        resourceId: 'a'
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 2',
        start: today + 'T09:30:00',
        end: today + 'T14:00:00',
        resourceId: 'b'
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 3',
        start: today + 'T08:30:00',
        end: today + 'T12:00:00',
        resourceId: 'c'
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 4',
        start: today + 'T10:30:00',
        end: today + 'T14:00:00',
        resourceId: 'd'
      }
    ]
  });
  calendar.render();
});

var value = 0;
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("displayValue");
var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
var minutes = slider.value % 60;
var seconds = minutes * 60;
var minuteOutput = $("#minutes")[0];
var hourOutput = $("#hours")[0];
var secondOutput = $("#seconds")[0];
var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
var minutes = slider.value % 60;
var seconds = minutes * 60;
hourOutput.innerHTML = hours;
minuteOutput.innerHTML = minutes;
secondOutput.innerHTML = seconds

$('.slider').change(function() {
  debugger;
  var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
  var minutes = slider.value % 60;
  var seconds = minutes * 60;
  hourOutput.innerHTML = hours;
  minuteOutput.innerHTML = minutes;
  secondOutput.innerHTML = seconds;
  slotduartion = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  if(calendar) {
    calendar.setOption('slotDuration', slotduartion);
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  color: var(--bs-link-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#storlekslider {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.9/index.global.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h3 id="displayValue">
    <span id="hours">min</span> :
    <span id="minutes">hour</span>
    <span id="seconds" style="display:none;">second</span>
  </h3>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="1440" value="500" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<br />
<div id='calendar'></div>
```